# Accepting only SSL connections to MS SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssl

I have followed http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316898 to force encryption on my MS SQL server. My intention is to reject any client connection that does not use SSL to connect. Am I on the right track?

Here is my detailed steps :

makecert -r -pe -n "CN=slc02xla.company.com" -b 01/01/2000 -e 01/01/2036 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ss my -sr localMachine -sky exchange -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12 c:\my.cer

I imported the same certificate into the trusted Root Certification Authorities Store

In SQL Server Configuration Manager, expandrf SQL Server Network Configuration, right-clicked Protocols for , and then selected Properties.

On the Certificate tab, selected the desired certificate from the Certificate drop-down menu, and then clicked OK.

On the Flags tab, selected Yes in the ForceEncryption box, and then clicked OK to close the dialog box.

Restarted the SQL Server service.

Anything missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the `Force Protocol Encryption` option in SQL Server Configuration Manager for the server then nothing but SSL will work (assuming you have a certificate configured).

Clearly, the only way to *know* is to **test**.  Use SSMS or SQLCMD to attempt a connection that does NOT use SSL.  If it connects, you have done something wrong.

Comment: i cannot format my comment, please see my edited question. thanks